# ¿Cómo puedo abrir una ventana desde múltiples botones en WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

¡Hola!, estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio con WPF, la app trata sobre el registro de pasajeros en una empresa de transportes, aquí está la imagen de la ventana.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, hay 15 asientos,(el del chofer no cuenta) y lo que quiero hacer es que al dar clic a cualquier asiento se abra la siguiente ventana.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta ventana voy a registrar los datos de los pasajeros, el problema aquí es que cuanto cierro esta ultima ventana (RegistrarPasajero) y quiero registrar los datos de otro pasajero en otro asiento dando clic a otro botón, **TODO** el programa se cierra.

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

Para la ventana donde se muestra el vehículo con los 15 asientos:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace AppTransporte
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para VehiculoPasajes.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class VehiculoPasajes : Page
    {
        RegistrarPasajero regPas = new RegistrarPasajero();
        public VehiculoPasajes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void btn_visImpresion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImprimirViajeActual imprVA = new ImprimirViajeActual();
        imprVA.Show();
    }
    private void boton_abrir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        regPas.Show();
    }
}
```

Y este es el código .xaml de los botones:

```
        <Button x:Name="boton_abrir" Content="01" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="736,202,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="59" Width="143" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="boton_abrir2" Content="02" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="736,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="98" Width="143" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_03" Content="03" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="587,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="88" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_04" Content="04" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="587,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="86" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_05" Content="05" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="587,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="87" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_06" Content="06" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="441,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="88" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_07" Content="07" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="441,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="86" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_08" Content="08" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="441,296,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="87" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_09" Content="09" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="294,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="88" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_10" Content="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="294,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="86" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_11" Content="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="294,296,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="87" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_12" Content="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="88" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_13" Content="13" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="86" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_15" Content="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,302,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_14" Content="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,238,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Width="122" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="boton_abrir_Click"/>
```

Y esta es la excepción que me aparece cuando quiero abrir la ventana RegistrarPasajero desde otro botón cualquiera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se puede establecer Visibility ni llamar a Show, ShowDialog o WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle después de haberse cerrado un elemento Window.'
```

Aquí está el código de RegistarPasajero:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace AppTransporte
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para RegistrarPasajero.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class RegistrarPasajero : Window
    {
        public RegistrarPasajero()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_cerrar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error no puede ser más claro, no puedes usar `Open` luego de haber usado `Close`, la solución ya la tienes en el caso `btn_visImpresion_Click` que es volver a instanciar la ventana

```
//RegistrarPasajero regPas = new RegistrarPasajero();

private void boton_abrir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   RegistrarPasajero regPas = new RegistrarPasajero();
   regPas.Show();
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, si funcionó!